# In angular/Javascript how to use masking for string inside a input html element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I wanted to mask string inside input html element using angular/Javascript.

Below is the image of one such example, is there any angular library available or how can do the same thing in Javascript.

[image]

For example:

[image]

So, whenever user will enter the input first he will get autosuggestion then based on the selected element he'll get input masking.

Suppose `substring(concat(input1,input2),3)` is the string then it has to have concat with only two elements should be allowed and for substring with only two elements with string and number type is acceptable. So, like this how can I add strings with masking.

I got one library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask but if nested string like concat inside substring how to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. Can you rephrase you question with more clear words. Also provide, the `expected output` and `expected input` clearly

Comment: I have updated the question, using auto suggest if I am taking conact function then it should have only two fileds , other than those two values it should not allow. Like masking phone number will have ten digits so, it'll allow only ten numbers. The strings may be of nested type.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide us with your code it would be a bit easier to answer but I think I understood the question correctly.

One way to do property binding in Angular is with {{ }} or [].

For example:

```
<input type="text" [value]="input1.substr(3).concat(input2.substr(3))"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" value="{{input1.substr(2).concat(input2)}}"/>
```

Stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klx3p6

This blog explains pretty well the different ways to do it and the differences.

https://blog.cloudboost.io/basic-data-binding-with-angular-67680fc149e6